# How should I set up test coverage with Karma, Webpack, ES6 and jQuery?

Tags: jquery, testing, karma-runner, webpack

I've found myself in a somewhat convoluted testing setup. I'm running Karma with Webpack and ES6 on jQuery code. I'm trying to test DOM-related functionality and I'd like to start off with a coverage report to see which functions I need to cover.

What is the best way to go about setting up test coverage? Should I use a Karma coverage preprocessor or Webpack `coverjs-loader`?

I'm currently running tests with `babel-node` --> `"test": "babel-node ./node_modules/.bin/karma start"`

Here's my current config:

### karma.conf.js

```
'use strict';
var path = require('path');
var webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config.babel');

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: path.resolve(__dirname),
    frameworks: ['mocha', 'sinon-chai'],
    exclude: [],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
    files: [
      'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js',
      'tests.webpack.js'
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      'tests.webpack.js': [ 'webpack', 'sourcemap' ]
    },
    reporters: [ 'dots' ],
    webpack: {
      devtool: 'inline-source-map',
      module: {
        loaders: [
          { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader' }
        ]
      },
      resolve: {
        modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', 'src'],
        extensions: ['', '.js']
      }
    },
    webpackServer: {
      quiet: true,
      noInfo: true
    },
    plugins: [
      'karma-mocha',
      'karma-sinon-chai',
      'karma-webpack',
      'karma-chrome-launcher',
      'karma-babel-preprocessor',
      'karma-sourcemap-loader'
    ]
  })
}
```

### tests.webpack.js

```
var context = require.context('./src', true, /spec\.js$/);
context.keys().forEach(context);
```